# Несколько полей не заносятся в базу данных

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Добавляю данные из формы. Код:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","form");

$date = $_POST['date'];
$period = $_POST['period'];
$vzroslye = $_POST['vzroslye'];
$deti = $_POST['deti'];
$phone = $_POST['[phone]'];
$fio = $_POST['[fio]'];


 
$hostname="localhost";
$username="root";
$dbname="form";
$pass="";
$usertable="form";
 
mysqli_connect ($hostname, $username, $pass);
mysqli_select_db ($con, $dbname);
 
$query="insert into $usertable (date, period, vzroslye, deti, phone, fio) values ('$date', '$period', '$vzroslye', '$deti', '$phone', '$fio')";
 
$result=mysqli_query ($con,$query);
 
if ($result == true)
print ("Данные занесены"); //Печать сообщения
else
print ("Данные не занесены");
```

Проблема заключается в том, что последние 2 поля: phone и fio не добавляются в базу...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот параметры этих столбцов в БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `$_POST['[phone]']`, `$_POST['[fio]']` ................ и что, ФИО реально в БД целое число?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский исправил скрин, но проблема не в этом

Comment: @АлексейШиманский благодарю, даже не заметил)